# Do multiple statis pods result in multiple Crystals?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I recently had a game where I found two Damaged Stasis Pods.  They take up a valuable augmentation slot so I'm not sure if there is any benefit to taking a second one.  I never found the Zoltan researchers to fix it, but if I had, would I have gotten two Crystals?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it does, but each Zoltan research station will only open up 1 pod.  To get 2 crystals, you will have to get that random event twice. ([source](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Augmentations#Damaged_Stasis_Pod))

Comment: Again, I am foiled by using http://ftlwiki.com